# Converting UTM32-EUREF89 shapefiles to align with Google maps

Tags: google-maps, google

Im from Denmark, where the maps we can get from official hand is in UTM32-EUREF89 shapefile format. When these are applied on top of either google/oracle/bing they seem to be like 20-25 km of towards the south or the y-axis if you prefer.
Im using QGIS 2.6.1 and have tried converting the maps to 3857 and 4326 but that does nothing. I seem to be doing something wrong. Can anybody maybe give me a hint, as to where I should look.

Regards, Jacob

Comment: Are thre any online resources available with this projection?

Comment: Check the CRS for the web service data. A north-south offset like that is classic for Mercator-defined-on-an-ellipsoid versus Mercator-defined-on-a-sphere which is what the web services should be using. ETRS89 approximately equals WGS84, so shouldn't be a datum transformation issue.

Comment: Hi guys, thankt for answering! I trying to find out what the CSR for the web service data. But it should be "standard Oracle".The *.prj file for the map, looks like this: PROJCS["UTM32_EUREF89",GEOGCS["GCS_EUREF89",DATUM["D_EUREF89",SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221008916]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",9],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: I'm guessing the "projection" Transverse_Mercator" is key here, but can I convert this with at tool like QGIS?